# Copying System32 DLL using MSYS breaks the 64bit being of the library

Tags: cp, msys, mingw-w64, system32

Under Windows 7 64bit, the *32.dll from System32 are 64bit libraries (according to Dependency Walker - [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) x64). A strange issue I noticed is that doing - for example - `cp /c/System32/ws2_32.dll /c/mingw64/some/lib/libws2_32.dll` in the MSYS Shell is breaking/converting the DLL to 32bit file (still according to Dependency Walker)... While copying/renaming it through Windows Explorer keep it unchanged... Still weird. If anyone has an explanation...

Or did I miss something about `cp` command usage...

***Note:** I already tried options like `--preserve=all` or `--symbolic-link`.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp` is somehow (either directly or due to the parent process that you're running it from) running as a 32-bit process. [File System redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is kicking in and you're actually copying `ws2_32.dll` from the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` directory instead - where it already exists as a 32-bit DLL.

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access.

Comment: Ok, excellent. `cp $WINDIR"/Sysnative/ws2_32.dll" /d/some/dir/libws2_32.dll` worked for me (MSYS being a 32 bit app.). Thanks for that.